# Set "data-remote" conditionally - Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

The html markup is as follows.

To send the ajax requests i use data-remote property.

```
<a class="text-blue fix-audit" href="<%= meter_path(@user, @property, audit_log) %>" data-remote="true" onclick="$('.ajax-loader-large').show();"> Fix  </a>
```

I need this data-remote property to execute only when a condition is satisfied.

If i append the property dynamically as follows, it is not working.

```
if(condition) { //condition is satisfied
   $('.fix-audit').attr("data-remote", "true")
}
```

How to accomplish this?

Comment: If you don't mind not using JQuery, you could use `setAttribute`(I just tested it, it works with data-remote): `document.querySelector('.fix-audit').setAttribute('data-remote', true)`

Comment: Actually, I just tested the code you posted (in the chrome console) and it works fine for me. When you say it's not working, do you mean you're getting an error, or just that the `data-remote` attribute doesn't get set?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the attribute with javascript as you're doing probably isn't working because the Rails UJS which looks for it has already been evaluated.

There are two solutions here:

1) Set the remote attribute server side

```
<a class="text-blue fix-audit" href="<%= meter_path(@user, @property, audit_log) %>" data-remote="<%= condition %>" onclick="$('.ajax-loader-large').show();"> Fix  </a>
```

2) Tell the Rails UJS to [evaluate the element](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/app/assets/javascripts/rails-ujs/features/remote.coffee#L16) again, after you've added the attribute

```
if(condition) { //condition is satisfied
   $('.fix-audit').attr("data-remote", "true")
   $.rails.handleRemote($('.fix-audit'))
}
```